# How to Session ID for a curl request?

Tags: curl

I'm trying to call and test CURL function for REST

```
  curl -H "Authorization: Bearer sessionId" "https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Account/0019000000xxxxH"
```

I tried curling with no session ID :)

```
 [{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]
```

So Curl is properly installed in windows. Where do I get the Session ID?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Login to salesforce organization
- Open developer console > execute anonymous
- Type following line. This gives current logged in user's session ID.:

  `SYSTEM.DEBUG('Session Id : ' +Userinfo.getSessionId());`

Above is the non-dynamic way to get session id. As you are just testing with cURL so this way will save your time.
But i will recommend to read [REST API](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/) to authenticate and get session Id a.k.a access token dynamically.

Comment: This may have worked when it was answered but it no longer works. The debug session says: USER_DEBUG [1]|DEBUG|Session Id : SESSION_ID_REMOVED

Answer (score 10):

I tried Ashwani's trick. It looks like security removes session id's from logs now. Here's a quick workaround.

```
SYSTEM.DEBUG('Session Id : ' +Userinfo.getSessionId().reverse())
```

Then you can just grab it from the log and reverse it again.